# Why can't I catch arp requests through tcpdump during ping?

Tags: networking, ping, tcpdump, arp, icmp

I use tcpdump to capture a ping operation, and I can get the icmp packet of ping 8.8.8.8, but I cannot capture the arp request through tcpdump.I wonder if anyone knows the reason for this? Thanks~
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdwBd.jpg)

Comment: Can you please add some code to your post showing what you have tried?

Comment: Also, please take the [tour] and read the [help], and feel free to ask on [meta] if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARP has a cache, and if the address is cached, there is no arp resolution going on.

Also since you are routing to 8.8.8.8, ARP is needed to resolve the address of next router (interface), which is probably used for a lot of other packets, so its address is likely cached, so no ARP resolution is actually taking place.

You can check [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1272010/where-is-the-arp-cache-on-linux/1272011) on how to view arp cache.

Comment: I think what you said makes sense, my arp cache table does have the mac address of the gateway, so it may be the gateway that went first, so there is no need for arp request. Thank you!